# Reading and writing current date to SharedPreferences using Calendar object

Tags: android, date, calendar, sharedpreferences

I want to write to preferences last date of update data in application. So I did like this

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("OrderOnline", 0);
Long updDate = settings.getLong("lastupdate", 0);
Long currdate= cal.getTimeInMillis();
if (!(updDate == currdate)) {
Log.d("AMainActivity", "updDate = " + updDate + "; currdate = " + currdate);
...
Editor ed = settings.edit();
        ed.putLong("lastupdate", currdate);
        ed.commit();
}
```

But this is not what I want. How can I read and write current date in SharedPreferences? I do not want to use any of *deprecated* objects. Thank you.

P.S. I do want current DATE in Preferences, not seconds. Now (!(updDate == currdate)) will always be True.

UPD
I add this

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("OrderOnline", 0);
Long updDate = settings.getLong("lastupdate", 0)/ MILLIS_PER_DAY;
Long currdate= cal.getTimeInMillis()/ MILLIS_PER_DAY;
if (!(updDate == currdate)) {
  Log.d("AMainActivity", "updDate = " + updDate + "; currdate = " + currdate);


...
  Editor ed = settings.edit();
        ed.putLong("lastupdate", currdate);
        ed.commit();
}
```

into {} This is the result

```
03-07 13:10:15.031: D/AMainActivity(9291): updDate = 15771; currdate = 15771
```

Something doesn't work.

Comment: What's deprecated here? Btw. you can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead of using the Calendar.

Comment: Nothing but I have not current DATE in preferences file. Now if-sentence will always be True.

Comment: Well it's quite logical that the amount of time that a milliseond-value you write to the settings is the same as the current milliseconds if exactly one millisecond. So perhaps you do not want to compare at millisecond level but on day level? It this what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to compare days instead of milliseconds:

```
long MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
long updDate = settings.getLong("lastupdate", 0) / MILLIS_PER_DAY;
long currdate= System.currentTimeMillis() / MILLIS_PER_DAY;

if (!(upDate == currDate)) ...
```

A short unit-test to proove things:
This writes "now that's what I thought" and "see, it works".

```
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    long MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    long updDate = 0 / MILLIS_PER_DAY;
    long currDate = System.currentTimeMillis() / MILLIS_PER_DAY;

    if (!(updDate == currDate)) {
        System.out.println("now that's what I thought");
    }

    updDate = System.currentTimeMillis() / MILLIS_PER_DAY;
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    currDate = System.currentTimeMillis() / MILLIS_PER_DAY;

    if (!(updDate == currDate)) {
        System.out.println("now that's STRANGE");
    } else {
        System.out.println("see, it works");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! What is the difference beetwen cal.getTimeInMillis() and System.currentTimeMillis()?

Comment: I updated my code to use long primitives instead of Long objects -- because comparing the objects with == does not work as expected (we'd have to use update.equals(currDate)).

Comment: Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() and System.currentTimeMillis() give the same value but with System.currentTimeMillis() you do not create a Calendar object so it's better for memory usage and performance.

Comment: with this "long" stll doesn't work properly. I used (upDate - currDate)>0 temporarly. I am still interesting why I cannot compare long values..

Comment: I added a short test method that prooves that you can compare longs :-)

Comment: ok, I checked, you are right, I will see for errors in my code